# Set attribute for each item with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, foreach, getelementsbytagname

I want to add an attribute to each item in my list.
I currently have the below which isn't working.
When I output the length of my var in the console outside the for loop it seems to output the correct number.
However when I try and apply an attribute in the for loop it isn't working because the length doesn't seem to be working?
What am I doing wrong here?  How can this be improved so that I can apply an attribute to each item in my list?

console.log

```
    test1 length || 3
    test2 length || 3
    test1||0
    TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function
```

```js
        var test1 = document.getElementById('test1').getElementsByTagName('a');
        var test2 = document.getElementById('test2').getElementsByTagName('div');
        console.log('test1 length || ' + test1.length);
        console.log('test2 length || ' + test2.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < test1.length; i++) {
          console.log('test1||' + i);
          this.setAttribute('title', 'test1' + i);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < test2.length; i++) {
          console.log('test2||' + i);
          this.setAttribute('title', 'test2' + i);
        }
```

```html
        <div id="test1">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
        </div>

        <div id="test2">
            <div class="item">1</div>
            <div class="item">2</div>
            <div class="item">3</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What made you think `this` would refer to a DOM element? I recommend to read the [**MDN documentation about `this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have got test as an array and looping through it you can reference that particular item with test[i].

this will be referring to window object.

replace

```
      this.setAttribute('title', 'test1' + i);
```

with

```
      test[i].setAttribute('title', 'test1' + i);
```

Same goes for test2 also.

Working output below

```js
var test1 = document.getElementById('test1').getElementsByTagName('a');
        var test2 = document.getElementById('test2').getElementsByTagName('div');
        console.log('test1 length || ' + test1.length);
        console.log('test2 length || ' + test2.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < test1.length; i++) {
          console.log('test1||' + i);
          test1[i].setAttribute('title', 'test1' + i);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < test2.length; i++) {
          console.log('test2||' + i);
         test2[i].setAttribute('title', 'test2' + i);
        }
```

```html
        <div id="test1">
            <a href="#">link 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 3</a>
        </div>

        <div id="test2">
            <div class="item">1</div>
            <div class="item">2</div>
            <div class="item">3</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `this` here

```
this.setAttribute('title', 'test2' + i);
```

You need to change it to

```
test1[i].setAttribute(...
```

and

```
test2[i].setAttribute(...
```

**Working:**

```
        var test1 = document.getElementById('test1').getElementsByTagName('a');
        var test2 = document.getElementById('test2').getElementsByTagName('div');
        console.log('test1 length || ' + test1.length);
        console.log('test2 length || ' + test2.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < test1.length; i++) {
          console.log('test1||' + i);
          test1[i].setAttribute('title', 'test1' + i);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < test2.length; i++) {
          console.log('test2||' + i);
          test2[i].setAttribute('title', 'test2' + i);
        }
```